# Strip Out The Last URL Name In String

Tags: perl, cgi

I need to strip out the last page name in a variable.

Here is my code so far but I loose the .jpg extension and I need to preserve it, Needed result: ImageName256.jpg

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

use CGI qw(:standard);
use CGI::Carp qw(warningsToBrowser fatalsToBrowser);


$Variable = "http://www.MyDomain.com/SomefolderPath/ImageName256.jpg";

($LastInUrl) = $Variable =~ m(.*/(\w+));

print $LastInUrl;
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
($LastInUrl) = (split qr{/}, $Variable)[-1];
```

Answer (score 6):

I usually avoid regexes for this sort of thing and handle it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use URI;
use URI::Escape qw( uri_unescape );
use File::Basename;

my $variable = "http://www.MyDomain.com/SomefolderPath/ImageName256.jpg";
my $last_in_url = uri_unescape( basename( URI->new( $variable )->path ) );

print $last_in_url;
```

---

Note: File::Basename's behaviour changes depending on which system it's used one. You'd have to use the following if you wanted portability:

```
my $fstype = fileparse_set_fstype('uri');
my $last = uri_unescape( basename( $uri->path ) );
fileparse_set_fstype($fstype);
```

Comment: `fileparse_set_fstype` does not have a `uri` type and will ignore anything it doesn't recognize, so `fileparse_set_fstype('uri')` is a no-op.  Say `fileparse_set_fstype("Unix")` instead.  In fact, there's no need to parse the path.  A slash in an unescaped URI path is unambiguous, there's no quoting or escaping like with a path.  `my($file) = $path =~ m{[^/](.*)$}`  But @ikegami's answer using path_segments() is better.

Comment: @Schwern, It's not a no-op, it's the same as `fileparse_set_fstype('Unix')`.

Comment: @ikegami You're right, I misread the code. *Technically* it's a documented use of the function, but fools the reader into thinking its doing something its not.

Answer (score 4):

```
use URI qw( );
my $uri = "http://www.MyDomain.com/SomefolderPath/ImageName256.jpg";
$uri = URI->new($uri);
my $basename = ( $uri->path_segments )[-1];
```

If you wanted to continue using a regex, you'd have to use the following:

```
use URI::Escape qw( uri_unescape );
my $uri = "http://www.MyDomain.com/SomefolderPath/ImageName256.jpg";
my $basename = $uri =~ m{/([^/#?]*)(?=[#?]|\z)} ? uri_unescape($1) : '';
```

Obviously, I strongly recommend the first solution over the second.

Comment: A caveat: `http://example.com/foo` will return `foo` but `http://example.com/foo/` will return an empty string.  Since the OP wants to get the file off the end this is probably ok, but I figured I'd note it.

Comment: @Schwern, `http://example.com/foo` and `http://example.com/foo/` are very different urls. It's to be expected that different values are returned. An empty string is being returned when the last segment is empty, which sounds quite appropriate.

Comment: I agree the behavior is totally correct, just might not be what the OP wants.